# How do I rewrite negb true to false in Coq?

Tags: coq

> How do I rewrite `negb true` to `false` in Coq?

I've been searching in the libraries for a simply way to rewrite `negb true` to `false`.

However, I haven't found anything useful.

I know of `simpl.`, but I prefer the more basic syntax.

Answer (score 4):

When you search for lemmas the search engine looks in the imported modules only.

That's why you first need to

```
Require Import Bool.
```

Then

```
Search (negb _ = false).
```

reveals the lemma

```
negb_false_iff: forall b : bool, negb b = false <-> b = true
```

You can use the lemma for rewriting if you `Require Import Setoid`.

```
Goal negb true = false.
  rewrite negb_false_iff. reflexivity. Qed.
```

You, probably, don't want to use `simpl` because you have `negb true` in some context and `simpl` messes up your goal/hypotheses, because it unfolds too much and creates large unreadable terms. You can narrow the context in which `simpl` applies by using it this way:

```
simpl (negb true).       (* rewrites `negb true` to `false` in the goal *)
```

or

```
simpl (negb true) in *.  (* rewrites `negb true` in the goal and hypotheses *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already know that [`simpl`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.simpl) will indeed reduce `negb true` to `false`.
This is because the two are definitionaly equivalent.

With this knowledge you could first prove the statement that you need, then rewrite with it:

```
assert (H: negb true = false) by reflexivity.
rewrite H.
```

But even better, you can use [`change`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.change) to do all of this in just one line:

```
change (negb true) with false.
```